# getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: javascript, react.js, state

Starting from React 16.3 there are some new lifecycle methods introduced. One of them is the `static getDerivedStateFromProps(props,state)` method. This method essentially synchronizes properties and state.

The `props` and `state` of a react component aren't always a one-on-one match. But for simple components often a couple of props do match exactly on the state.

It's not strictly necessary to have this `getDerivedStateFromProps(...)` method actually. If your component doesn't really have an internal state, then there is no need to worry about it.

Anyway, in a case where there is an exact match of `props` and `state` I am trying to find the most elegant way to write this code.

The following is rather verbose:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  // these 3 properties can change over time.
  const activeBaseNode = props.activeBaseNode;
  const filterOID = props.filterOID;
  const quickFilterRequest = props.quickFilterRequest;

  // compare them to the state
  if ((state.filterOID !== filterOID) || 
    (state.activeBaseNode !== activeBaseNode) || 
    (state.quickFilterRequest !== quickFilterRequest)) {

    // updates the state
    return ({ activeBaseNode, filterOID, quickFilterRequest });
  }

  // no changes --> no updates
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to clone them into state? You would be able to use `this.props` directly inside your component?

Comment: this.props changes will not cause a rerender

Comment: That depends on your `shouldComponentUpdate`. React wants to limit the usage of `getDerivedStateFromProps` - see https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Comment: I would have to guess the users that voted to put this on hold as off topic didn't understand what they were looking at. @TobySpeight

Comment: @Ted, that's spot on ! My guess is that @TobySpeight, @Quill, @t3chb0t and @Dannnno are not aware of the changes in react version 16.3 which introduced the `getDerivedStateFromProps` method. I don't see how any more context than that is possibly needed. https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/29/react-v-16-3.html

Comment: Even though I strongly disagree with the decision to close this topic, I did an edit of the question and added more context. - Now, can we reopen it ? - I actually have an anwser I want to share with the other people who were involved in this thread. *sigh*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ted's answer is quite readable to me.

You could use `some` to detect if you need to submit changes as that is semantically closer to what you are doing:

```
if (['activeBaseNode', 'filterOID', 'quickFilterRequest']
    .some(prop => state[prop] !== props[prop])
```

It's perhaps nicer to reverse the logic with `every` and early exit, then extract all the properties only when you need them. Here I'm doing it with a function, avoiding defining three `const`s:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  if (['activeBaseNode', 'filterOID', 'quickFilterRequest']
    .every(prop => state[prop] === props[prop]) return null

  return (({activeBaseNode, filterOID, quickFilterRequest}) => 
         ( {activeBaseNode, filterOID, quickFilterRequest}))(props)
```

That's cryptic and short approach.

I don't really like that the names of the properties are repeated three times in all the solutions. To avoid that, a `reduce` can be used to build the properties that need to be updated:

```
const toUpdate = ['activeBaseNode', 'filterOID', 'quickFilterRequest']
  .find(prop => state[prop] !== props[prop])
  .reduce((m,k) => m[k] = props[k], {})
return Object.keys(toUpdate).length == 0 ? null : toUpdate
```

Once you get used to it, I think that's the clearest. It's got the essence of the problem and nothing more: the names of the properties, that the state != the props, and that you return `null` if nothing is changing.

Comment: After reading the answer of Ted, I was also going in the direction that you put here. Not bad. I just wish there was a way to do it without declaring the fields as strings, ('cause I just know, that's where I'll make bugs/typos).  But hey, It's an improvement for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possibility:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  const { activeBaseNode, filterOID, quickFilterRequest } = props;

  let updateState = false;
  ['activeBaseNode', 'filterOID', 'quickFilterRequest'].forEach(item => {
    if(state[item] !== props[item]){
      updateState = true;
    }
  });

  return updateState ? ({ activeBaseNode, filterOID, quickFilterRequest }) : null;
}
```

Comment: I really like the improvement of the `const {a,f,q} = props` which is straightforward. I'm not a big fan of string arrays. But hey, it's an improvement for sure.